# Can multiple test plans along with test suites and test results be added to the new test plan>

Tags: azure, testing

Test plan A has multiple test suites. I need to create new Test plan B and move all the test suites and test cases associated with test suite to test plan B. When moving test suites from test plan A to test plan B I should be able to move all the test run details as well. Can this be done in Azure? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

By design, *Test Runs* are specific to a *Test Plan*. The overall status of a Test Plan is comprised of many different test runs over time.

While there is no native capability in the user-interface to move data between plans, when you execute a manual *Test Run* the tooling uses the available REST APIs for interacting with Test Plans. You could use the REST API to simulate re-running the tests by creating new Test Runs with previous values.

This is assuming that we're only interested in outcomes, excluding attachments and other details. You would need to:

1. Locate previous test runs that were associated to the test run using [Test Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) endpoint
2. For each test run, you would need to fetch the details for each individual test run using the [Test Results - Get Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/results/get-test-results) endpoint. For each TestCaseResult, make a note of the following:

   - test case id
   - test configuration id
   - outcome

   > **Tip**:
   > you could store these in a csv in the following format:
   >
   > `<test-configuration-id>_<test-case-id>, outcome`
3. Each *Test Case* in your *Test Plan* is associated with a *Test Configuration*. The combination of *Test Plan* + *Test Configuration* + *Test Case* is represented as a *Test Point*. You will need to locate the Test Points for your new Test Plan using the [Test Point - Get Points List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-point/get-points-list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2).

   > **Tip**:
   >
   > You can retrieve all the test points in a test plan by specifying the root suite id and the recursive flag. The root suite id can be located in your browser's url when viewing the suites in your plan.

   Make a note of the following:

   - test case id
   - test configuration id
   - test point id

   > **Tip**:
   >
   > You could store these in a csv in the following format:
   >
   > `<test-configuration-id>_<test-case-id>, <test-point-id>`
4. For each of the previous test runs, map the *Test Case + Test Configuration* identifiers to the *Test Point* identifiers in the new *Test Plan*, then use the [Test Runs - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) endpoint to create a new *Test Run* against the target *Test Plan*. The body of the request only needs to include the array of `pointIds`. Make note of the test run id after it is created.
5. Now that we have a Test Run that refers to the test cases we want to update, use the [Get Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/results/get-test-results?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) endpoint to get the list of *TestCaseResults*. Make a note of the following:

   - id
   - configuration.id
   - testcase.id
   - testpoint.id
6. You now have the data points needed to copy the original test outcomes to then corresponding *TestCaseResults*. Use the [Test Results - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) endpoint to push the updated *TestCaseResults* back to the server.
7. Finally, you need to mark that the test run is complete using the [Test Run - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/runs/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)